# Архитектура чата

Tags: c#, highload, сокет, tcp, wcf

Требования:

1. Чат двух клиентов
2. Групповые разговоры
3. Получение оффлайн сообщений
4. Сохранение истории(собственно, вытекает из третьего пункта)
5. Требования, не столь относящееся к вопросу: регистрация, авторизация через сторонние сервисы (google, ms live), пользователь может указывать доп. информацию о себе, приём/передача файлов напрямую между клиентами и через сервер.

Задача в целом из спортивного интереса. Предположим, что клиентов будет до 10k, само приложение будет развиваться и его будет нужно поддерживать.

---

Не могу определиться, как сделать удобнее:

1. Опрашивать сервер постоянно на наличие изменений
2. Поддерживать перманентное сокет соединение

Проблемы с первым вариантом - это ведь ресурсоёмко очень. Каждый запрос нужно валидировать, частое обращение к базе.

Второй вариант труден в реализации и в поддержке. Собственно, есть такая идея: развернуть wcf-сервис, сообщения отправлять через него (like a `SendMessage(message, userId)`). Кроме того, предоставлять также точку подключения к сокету, который уже это сообщение доставлять получателю.

То есть, действия клиента: авторизовался -> подключился к сокету -> отправил сообщение через wcf-сервис

wcf-сервис: получил сообщение -> нашёл "сокет-соединение" получателя -> отправил сообщение через tcp

---

Собственно, что легче поддерживать и что "дешевле" - тысячи TCP соединений или тысячи тысяч запросов на сервер?

Заранее огромное спасибо!

ps. использовать state-соединение wcf-сервиса предлагать, наверное, не стоит. Конечный клиент должен работать на нескольких платформах + начитался о них много нехорошего.

Comment: Ничего конкретного не скажу, просто дам ссылку на java сервер - клиент. Так для общего интереса http://inetjava.sourceforge.net/lectures/part1_sockets/InetJava-1.9-Chat-Client-Server-Example.html

Comment: А может взять готовый jabber сервер? они поддерживают почти все, что перечислено.

Comment: @KoVadim, тогда спортивный интерес теряется ;)

Comment: взять на посмотреть. Потом, написав свое решение, сравнить, потестить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется, что для 10k пользователей было бы лучше использовать не WCF, а какой нибудь messaging service аля NServiceBus, Nancy или ServiceStack. К тому же они более толерантны к ошибкам и их (насколько я знаю) проще отлавливать (ошибки). 
Как мне кажется, это идеальный и ресурсоэкономичный вариант для такого типа задачи. К тому же получишь еще бонус в масштабируемости приложения. Проще будет разделять на модули и